# Pronunciation of "intermediate" as /ɪntə(ɹ)ˈmiːdʒɪt/?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, subcontinental-english, received-pronunciation

I've heard both "intermediate" and "immediate" pronounced /ɪntə(ɹ)ˈmiːdʒɪt/ and /ɪˈmiːdʒɪt/ respectively in Indian English. Wiktionary has /ɪˈmiːdʒɪt/ as an alternative pronunciation for immediate for RP but not for intermediate. Is /ɪntə(ɹ)ˈmiːdʒɪt/ a legitimate pronunciation?

Comment: I've heard /ɪntə(ɹ)ˈmiːdʒɪt/. The suffix "-diate" is often shortened to /-dʒɪt/, at least in BE.

Comment: Unstressed syllables in English beginning with /d/ followed by /y/ or /i/ are prone to palatalize the /dy/ into /dʒ/; it's been a feature of many dialects for centuries.